# Error Deploying Asp.Net Minimal API (Top level statements) to lambda using CDK

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, minimal-apis

I have a CDK solution with a stack etc and in the same solution i have created a ASP.NET minimal API Lambda project.

When I deploy using the CDK I'm getting the ERROR:

`Internal Server Error`

When I check the logs I can see the Error:

`Error: executable assembly /var/task/lambdaMinimalApi.dll was not found.`.

I know what this error is, it is trying to find the Lambda function thinking its a libary, but mine is an executable. I know this as when i deploy the lambda with:

`dotnet lambda deploy-function`

through trial an error i found out this:

.NET Lambda projects that use C# top level statements like this project must be deployed as an executable assembly instead of a class library. To indicate to Lambda that the .NET function is an executable assembly the `Lambda function handler value` is set to the .NET Assembly name. This is different then deploying as a class library where the function handler string includes the assembly, type and method name.

Following this and just using the assembly name I can deploy and everything works.

But when it comes to the CDK I get the internal server error mentioned above.

My public repo is here: https://github.com/RollsChris/cdk-twitter-clone-dotnet

I think it will be a good example to add to the official examples if I can get it to work?

I have tried various forms of Code.From**, and searched the internet far and wide.
Most examples are using a lambda function written in javascript but the CDK is using .NET.

Thanks

Comment: if I understood correctly, your problem is to how to deploy lambda written in .net with cdk ?

Comment: Its an ASP.Net minimal API, with top level statements and I want to deploy using CDK. I emphasis the top level statement as I know this dictates what function-handler you put. If I deploy just using "dotnet lambda deploy-function" everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your repo and the error message in the question...

> Error: executable assembly /var/task/lambdaMinimalApi.dll was not
> found.

Could it be the project is outputing a DLL called `lambdaMinimalAPI` but your code is specifying different casing (pascal casing API at the end)

```cs
var lambdaFunction = new Function(this, "lambdaMinimalAPI", new FunctionProps
{
    Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_6,
    Code = Code.FromAsset("src/lambdaMinimalApi",assetOptions),
    Handler = "lambdaMinimalApi",
    Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["userProfilesTable"] = userProfilesTable.TableName,
        ["tweetsTable"] = tweetsTable.TableName,
    },
    MemorySize = 256,
    Timeout = Duration.Seconds(30),
    Architecture = Architecture.X86_64
});
```

Hanlder should be like so:

```cs
Handler = "lambdaMinimalAPI", // UPPERCASE API
```